# Assert Error: list_length(portal->parseTrees) > 1 in Redshift on MERGE operations

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have a merge statement in a stored procedure which looks like -

```
MERGE INTO  table1
 USING table2 as source ON table1.id = source.table2.id
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE
     SET 
         <some columns of target = source.some colmns>

 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT  <columns>
 VALUES (source.columns);
```

And the stored procedure frequently errors out at this statement with **Assert:  error:  Assert  code: 1000,  context:   list_length(portal->parseTrees) > 1**
This is being run on Redshift.

I am expecting it to not error out. One solution was to rewrite it into insert and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have likely guessed "assert" errors are not good.  Redshift likely found an internal data violation when executing the statements.  You will want to try updating your cluster to see if they have fixed a known issue and if it continues send in a support ticket or submit to https://repost.aws/

Rewriting your code has a good chance of avoiding whatever issue (theirs or yours) which is causing the error. So this is a good way to get past the issue for now.  Still a good idea to have the RS team look at it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do you have more context on what Assert: error: Assert code: 1000, context: list_length(portal->parseTrees) > 1 could mean. Might help me to pinpoint what kind of data will cause this issue in the future.

Comment: As I understand it assert errors happen when Redshift is checking data / data structure validity during execution.  A safety check that the actions the db is performing are of expected type, size, structure etc.  This prevents unexpected things from making a mess of the database. Basically the RS code got to a place it shouldn't have gotten to.  These can be caused by bugs in Redshift (compiler or db code), bugs in user provided code (like a UDF or SP), a problem with the data, or any combination of these.   They mostly happen with "interesting" stored procedures but I've seen other cases.